# Passing List to method throws an error

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am passing a List of table rows to a method inside an adapter. If I create the List and then pass it to the method it crashes. I found a way to make it work but do not know how to describe it or why it works. Please help me understand.

```
public class CatalogGridView extends Activity {
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    //List<Poster> posters = db.getAllPosters(); <-- Here I have commented out the problem. If I pass "posters" to the setData method it crashes.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_grid_view);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ImageAdapter mGridviewAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        mGridviewAdapter.setData(db.getAllPosters());
        //If I do it this way, it works.
        //---------------------------------------------------------

        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }
```

Here is the method which is inside my adapter.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
//I define the posterList as:
List<Poster> posterList = new ArrayList<Poster>(0);

    public void setData(List<Poster> posters){
        for (Poster p : posters){
            Log.d("posters", p.getPosterFilename());
        }
        posterList.addAll(posters);
    }
}
```

This is my db method

```
public List<Poster> getAllPosters() {
        List<Poster> posterList = new ArrayList<Poster>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + "posters ORDER BY presenter_lname, presenter_fname";

//Line 99 is getWritableDatabase====================================================    
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Poster poster = new Poster(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8));

                // Adding contact to list
                posterList.add(poster);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        // return contact list
        return posterList;
    }
```

The LogCat was hard to decipher but I could tell something was going on with the SQL

```
12-08 21:34:08.320: E/AndroidRuntime(22045): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 21:34:08.320: E/AndroidRuntime(22045):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
12-08 21:34:08.320: E/AndroidRuntime(22045):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
12-08 21:34:08.320: E/AndroidRuntime(22045):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
12-08 21:34:08.320: E/AndroidRuntime(22045):    at com.myapp.e_posterviewer.MySQLiteHelper.getAllPosters(MySQLiteHelper.java:99)
12-08 21:34:08.320: E/AndroidRuntime(22045):    at com.myapp.e_posterviewer.CatalogGridView.<init>(CatalogGridView.java:26)
```

Comment: what code have you written at MySQLiteHelper.java line 99?

Comment: May be your `posters=null`

Comment: can you please post getAllPosters() code ?

Comment: @Hector I have posted the db method and highlighted line 99

Comment: @MD If I do it the way that I show the expected data is there. posters is not null

Comment: When you get always try to open database for read instead of write like :  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase()

Comment: @Haresh does this add efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
List<Poster> posters = db.getAllPosters();
```

Move this line to inside `onCreate()` method.

The `Activity` is created only after call of `onCreate()` you are creating database object outside of the methhod so here `context` is `null`

Comment: ok, so any references to "this" have to be made after onCreate??

Comment: Activity context is made

Comment: @silversunhunter you are calling glaobally at that time activity is not created

Answer (score 2):

you are creating an object of MySQLiteHelper and passing the context as this which is null and causing the trouble move this to oncreate and it will be fine.

Comment: Expanding upon this suggestion: turn `MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);` to `MySQLiteHelper db;` and `List<Poster> posterList = db.getAllPosters();` to `List<Poster> posterList;`. Then, in `onCreate()`, after the `inflater` call, put the lines `db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);` and `posterList = db.getAllPosters();`. Using `this` outside of `onCreate` is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Until you do this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

the value of `this` would be null. So effectively You are not initialising the object `db` properly. Declare the variables globally(If you really want them globally) and initialise it inside `onCreate` as shown below:

```
public class CatalogGridView extends Activity {

    MySQLiteHelper db;    
    List<Poster> posters;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_grid_view);

        db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        posters = db.getAllPosters();

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ImageAdapter mGridviewAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        mGridviewAdapter.setData(posters);

        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Oncreate()` Method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_grid_view);
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ImageAdapter mGridviewAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    mGridviewAdapter.setData(db.getAllPosters());
    //If I do it this way, it works.
    //---------------------------------------------------------

    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

}
```